Interpolate from points from one vector layer along line vector using QGIS
I am trying to make a map in QGIS of change in nutrient concentrations along a river based on stations along the river. The simplest approach would seem to be to add the points to the line keeping their nutrient value attributes and then interpolating between points along the line. I have not been able to find a solution using that approach.
I have also tried making a polygon from buffering the line, constructing a grid within that polygon in the hope of interpolating between nutrient value points onto the grid.
Here is a picture of that approach.

I have not been able to make that work either.
Here is a figure showing the river (blue) and the sampling points (colors represent nitrate values).

This is a figure from a published paper showing what I am trying to produce.
The river line is "gradational" colors based on concentration.
The points are the stations that have values.

I would like to show the same thing for my nutrient data.
How should I proceed?

one possible solution would be:

Interpolate by Inverse distance a new raster layer over your points


Buffer your line layer (river)


Clip the Raster with the buffered line layer as mask



